# ArrayList, почему нельзя добавлять элементы непосредственно в конструктор

Tags: java

// Не компилируется

List list1 = new ArrayList<>("efefef", "fefe", "fefef");

// Всё хорошо

List list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("efefef", "fefe",));

// Всё тоже хорошо, но в чём отличие

List list1 = Arrays.asList("efefef", "fefe", "fefef");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У `ArrayList` просто нет такого конструктора.

Существует только 3 конструктора, с их помощью можно только задать начальную вместимость массива `public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)` или, как вы указали, передать коллекцию `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`. Ну и конечно есть конструктор без параметров `public ArrayList()`.

В последнем случае будет не совсем простой `ArrayList`, а несколько изменённый, с фиксированным размером, т.е. в него нельзя вставить элементы, а также удалять.

Answer (score 1):

У arraylist нет конструктора, позволяющего инициализировать list элементами.

Для этого есть сторонние библиотеки, например guava

```
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("1", "2", "3");
```

В Java 9 можно использовать

```
List<String> list = List.of("1", "2", "3");
```

Answer (score 0):

У ArrayList не конструктора принимающего массив строк, но есть конструктор принимающий наследника Collections, таким образом можно создавать аррэй на основе другой коллекции. А ещё 1 конструктор насколько я понял не добавили из-за обратной совместимости.